# Let file:// access http://localhost

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, google-chrome

I have 2 files: **`file.html`** on my desktop, and **`local.html`** on my localhost. Is it possible to let the file access the localhost? Currently, I have this error on Chrome:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from
>   accessing a frame with origin "http://localhost".  The frame
>   requesting access has a protocol of "file", the frame being accessed
>   has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.

A .htaccess solution is prefered, but `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *` does not work.

Comment: Accepted answer (in 9 minutes).

Comment: Might help: [Disable same origin policy in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)

Comment: I've just added this as an alternative answer, thank you anyway, that helped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that.  (except by bypassing policies entirely with JSONP)

You should avoid `file://` entirely.

Answer (score 0):

**Restart Chrome with the `--disable-web-security` flag.**

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3177718/1293492

Comment: As noted in the name, you should never actually use that.

Comment: Indeed, it's not recommended.